# Seaborn and Pandas: How to set yticks formatted as UK pounds

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to format the yticks of a plot as pounds with a '£' and ideally a comma separator. Currently the yticks are represented like this: 20000, 30000, 40000. I'm aiming for this: £20,000, £30,000, £40,000, etc.

Here is an equivalent reproducible example:

```
import seaborn as sis
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, whis=np.inf)
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, jitter=True)
```

How would I format these yticks like this: £12.00, £10.00, £8.00, etc.

After 3 hours of googling and failing with all sorts of `plt.ytick` and `ax.set_yticklabels` options I'm totally lost.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `StrMethodFormatter`, which uses the `str.format()` specification mini-language.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# The next line uses `utf-8` encoding. If you're using something else
#     (say `ascii`, the default for Python 2), use
#     `fmt = u'\N{pound sign}{x:,.2f}'`
#     instead.
fmt = '£{x:,.2f}'
tick = mtick.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick) 

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, whis=np.inf, ax=ax)
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="tip", data=tips, jitter=True, ax=ax)
```

[image: y-labels in pounds]

The comma in `fmt = '£{x:,.2f}'` turns on the thousands separator, so it'll also work as you want for higher amounts.

Comment: Looks like a brilliant solution. Any idea why it works for you, but when I run your code I get: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: You must be using an encoding different from `utf-8`. Try `fmt = u'\xA3{x:,.2f}'` instead.

Comment: In fact, the error message says you're using `ascii` instead of `utf-8`.

Comment: Your 1st comment fixed the issue perfectly. Thx.

Comment: Another option seems to be `fmt = u'\N{pound sign}{x:,.2f}'`. More readable than an obscure code point.

Comment: The default encoding in Python 2 is `ascii`, the default one in Python 3 is `utf-8`. So anybody using Python 2 would run into this. I've edited my answer to reflect this.